# New certificate on Squid reverse proxy

Tags: certificate, reverse-proxy

I need to create a New certificate on Squid reverse proxy to replace an expired one.
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), see especially [`HOWTO certificates`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt), and note paragraph 4, *Creating a self-signed test certificate*.

The squid doc [*OpenSSL Configuration for CA and Certificate Generation*](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/SslWithWildcardCertifiate#head-d784a4e7fbe00e19a5f312c6223b8e0a461a14ca)
provides full details on using `OpenSSL` for generating a certificate and using it with `Squid`.